# Include two email addresses in mailmessage.replyto

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code in my mailmanager.cs:

```
m_replyTo="abc@qwe.com, asd@asd.cvb"

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_replyTo))
                {
                    mailMessage.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(m_replyTo);
                }
```

I see that mailmessage.replyto is only taking the first email address. How can i have it take both?

Comment: `ReplyTo` will only take one email. Use `cc` to copy other email.

Comment: Use `ReplyToList` to put more than one email address

Answer (score 4):

Use ReplyToList to put more than one email address

```
mailMessage.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress("abc@qwe.com"));
mailMessage.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress("asd@asd.cvb"));
```

or

```
mailMessage.ReplyToList.Add("abc@qwe.com");
mailMessage.ReplyToList.Add("asd@asd.cvb");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
To reply more than one email address use the below code

string  m_replyTo = "abc@qwe.com, asd@asd.cvb";

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_replyTo))
                {
                    foreach (var address in m_replyTo.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    {
                        mailMessage.ReplyToList.Add(address);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage' does not contain a definition for 'ReplyToList' and no extension method 'ReplyToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage' could be found